# replace chracter with new line using sed command in PHP file

Tags: php, bash, sed

I am working on PHP file. I process some text file and want to replace each occurrence of '< ' with a new line.

I am using sed command:

```
shell_exec("C:\\cygwin64\\bin\\bash.exe --login -c 'sed -i -r \'s/'< '/'\n'/\' $text_files_path/diffFile.txt 2>&1'");
```

But, it doesn't work.

I were using:

```
shell_exec("C:\\cygwin64\\bin\\bash.exe --login -c 'sed -i -r \'s/.{2}//\' $text_files_path/diffFile.txt 2>&1'");
```

to delete the 1st two characters from each line.

And:

```
shell_exec("C:\\cygwin64\\bin\\bash.exe --login -c 'sed -i -r \'s/.{2}/*/\' $text_files_path/diffFile.txt 2>&1'");
```

to replace the 1st two characters with *

The two characters are '< '. And now I want to replace them with a new line.

**Solution:**

I solve the problem with:

```
shell_exec("C:\\cygwin64\\bin\\bash.exe --login -c \"sed -i -r 's/< /\\r\\n/' $text_files_path/diffFile.txt 2>&1\"");
```

For new line, I wrote: `\\r\\n` instead of `\\n`.
Many thanks @Tom Fenech.

Comment: Try `shell_exec("C:\\cygwin64\\bin\\bash.exe --login -c "tr '< ' '\n' < $text_files_path/diffFile.txt 2>&1"");`

Comment: @heemayl not working. I prefer using sed.

Comment: Notice that @heemayl put a space after the < character, like you did in your question. If that's the case, then your question should be edited accordingly. Moreover, it is possible that you fail to quote your instruction, but you did not specify that in your comment. On any case "Not working" means almost nothing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to adjust your use of quotes and escape your newline character:

```
shell_exec("C:\\cygwin64\\bin\\bash.exe --login -c \"sed -i -r 's/< /\\n/' $text_files_path/diffFile.txt 2>&1\"");
```

I'm using (escaped) double quotes around the bash command and single quotes around the sed command. I also changed `\n` to `\\n`, as backslashes need to be escaped within double quotes.

Comment: it just delete '< ' and not replace it with new line.

Comment: If your file has Windows line endings then you'll have to use `\\r\\n` instead of just `\\n`.

Comment: OMG! you solve a problem which takes more than ONE WEEK to solve! Thanks a lot dear.